# How to refactor frontend JS to Angular 2 to play nicely with PHP MVC backend?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a huge PHP MVC web application, which now uses for some click events and modal dialog rendering jQuery. To stay confident with modern frontend technologies, I would like to refactor the JavaScript code to run under Angular 2. But my main question is: How can I do this? Angular 2 doesn't have controllers anymore, which really complicate things in my use case. I mainly just need some click event subscribing and modal dialog handling on the JavaScript side. The most part of the HTML is rendered in the PHP backend.

For example, let's say we have a news site (route: index/news) with many news entries. Actually, this is completely done in the backend by fetching data from the database, load a helper for each news entry and output it in the view. If I would refactor this to a component, then I would have massively ajax requests for each news entry. I believe this is not the preferred way of using Angular 2. Also, what I really need is some interaction on buttons etc.. I think it is also not the meaning of Angular 2 to create a small template string with the buttons and an ngClick inside of that, just for having an ngClick on my button.

So, please tell me how I can integrate Angular 2 in a nice way, so that these two technologies play well with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even tho you're getting downvotes, let me help you to start a **BIG journey** if you're willing to really do that.

---

First, if your views are generated on the backend :

> "The most part of the HTML is rendered in the PHP backend."

According to that sentence, I imagine that you don't have a REST API. `Single Page Application` are meant to live in the browser without reloading the whole page. This is going to be a problem with your current stack. (otherwise, there's no point doing SPA).

So I'd propose you to stop generating views from your backend and return raw data (json objects). To do that, read some articles about REST APIs.

---

Then, you'll need to start learning Angular2 and understand SPA logic.
I'd recommend you to take a look to the official website : http://angular.io

---

Honnestly, this is a very big step forward and I'm not sure you'll be able to do that with en existing app. BUT, it's very interesting for sure and you might want to learn more about all that before your make/participate to an other project.

Good luck

Comment: Well, yes, the main part is rendered on the backend side. And I would need Angular 2 just for some click events or stuff like that. So, is Angular 2 made only for SPA? Is this simply not possible with my project?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use Angular2 for this use case. **Angular2 is way too overkill for "handling some click events"**. Plus, unless you dig into AOT and tree shaking, your generated JS will be pretty huge, the bootstrap time will be long and the first paint will take many seconds. I'm a big Angular2 fan, but here if it's really simple use JQuery (I'd never thought I'd recommend that anymore) or if you need tight synchronization between View and Model maybe take a look to Vue.js (which is smaller).

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, Angular 2 is really the wrong thing for me. The big advantage that we have from Angular over jQuery is the once reading against the DOM while initializing instead of querying the DOM again each time we register a click handler. In Angular 1 it was easy to do this, by just creating an controller. But Anular 1 is not future save, so I should really use Vue.js. My main intention was to get a cleaner javascript with less overhead and a nice structure.

Comment: I haven't used Vues.js but from what I read and some dev feedbacks I really think you should use it instead of angular2 :) Plus, the latest version of Vue.js has super benchmarks (better than Angular2) and keep things very simple (once again, from what I heard). Good luck :)